# function orders in C++

Tags: c++, function, c++11, vector

I'm new to C++. There are three functions in my program.
The first one works same as np.linspace in python. The later two both take in a 2d vector, an integer and return a 2d vector.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


vector<float> linspace(float start, float end, int step);
vector< vector<float> > angleDisc(vector < vector<float> > data, int theta_loc);
vector< vector<float> > ringDisc(vector < vector<float> > data, int r_loc);

const float R_M = 18, RESO_R = 80;
const float RESO_THETA = 60;
const float PI = 3.14159;

const vector<float> DIS_R = linspace(0, R_M, RESO_R);
const vector<float> DIS_THETA = linspace(0, PI/2, RESO_THETA);

int main() {
    vector < vector<float> > inner = {{0.1, 0.000001},{1,-2},{-2,3},{1,3},{6,1},{4,-4},{1,3.2},{4,5.7}};

    vector< vector<float> > angled = angleDisc(inner, 0);
    //vector< vector<float> > ringd = ringDisc(inner, 0);

    for(int j = 0; j < angled.size(); j++){

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        cout << angled[j][i] << " ";
        }
        cout << "next" << endl;

        return 0;
    }

vector<float> linspace(float start, float end, int step){
    vector<float> stairs;
    float increment = (end - start) / step;
    for (int i = 0; i <= step; i++){
        stairs.push_back(i * increment);
    }
    return stairs;
}

vector< vector<float> > angleDisc(vector < vector<float> > data, int theta_loc){
   vector< vector < vector<float> > > pieced_disc( DIS_THETA.size() );
   float angle;

   for (int i = 0; i <= DIS_THETA.size() - 1; i++){
       for (int k = 0; k <= data.size() - 1; k++){
           angle = abs( atan( data[k][1] / data[k][0]));
           if ( (angle > DIS_THETA[i]) && (angle <= DIS_THETA[i+1]) ){
               pieced_disc[i].push_back(data[k]);
               data.erase(data.begin() + k - 1 );
           } 
       }
   }
   return pieced_disc[theta_loc];
}


vector< vector<float> > ringDisc(vector < vector<float> > data, int r_loc){
   vector< vector < vector<float> > > ringed_disc( DIS_R.size() );
   float r;

   for (int i = 0; i <= DIS_R.size() - 1; i++){
       for (int k = 0; k <= data.size() - 1; k++){
           r = sqrt(pow(data[k][0], 2) + pow(data[k][1], 2));
           if ( (r > DIS_R[i]) && (r < DIS_R[i+1]) ){
               ringed_disc[i].push_back(data[k]);
               data.erase(data.begin() + k - 1 );
           }
       }
   }
   return ringed_disc[r_loc];
}
```

Though this works fine but if I uncomment the:

```
vector< vector<float> > ringd = ringDisc(inner, 0);
```

in the main function. The code could still be compiled successfully but executing the object file doesn't return anything, I have to press "Control + C" to exit.

I have tried:
1) flip the order of function angleDisc() and ringDisc(), in this case, ringDisc(), which goes first, could print the result in main function but the angle disc can't.

2) Let ringDisc() be exactly the same as angleDisc, but only the function names are different, this time, both function could work properly.

I am really confused, could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you try to debug the code with a debugger?

Comment: Aside: `i <= DIS_R.size() - 1` is more commonly rendered `i < DIS_R.size()`

Comment: Aside: rather than two element `vector<float>`, why not `struct point { float x; float y; float angle() const; float distance() const; };`?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I *think* you are trying to find all the points in a certain range of angle or magnitude

Comment: E.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e266daa0a5a9aee

Comment: @Caleth yes, I am trying to "find all the points in a certain range of angle or magnitude". Thanks for your answer though I don't quite understand since I am really a newbie in C++, I could only write basic codes.

Comment: @Caleth I checked the link you sent, thanks! I've learned a lot.

Comment: Even more tidied up: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d92f24767226115

Answer (score 2):

Your program has [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), because (initially, when `k == 0`) you try to

```
data.erase(data.begin() - 1);
```

and again when `i == DIS_R.size() - 1` you try

```
DIS_R[i+1]
```

*Why* are you removing elements from `data` whilst iterating over it? That would result in only visiting half the elements

Comment: Umm, could be one of the reasons.

Comment: could you explain this in a more detailed way? what do you mean by undefined behavior?

Comment: undefined behaviour means the compiler is allowed to substitute *anything* for your program

Comment: I deleted `erase` then the code works. The reason why I wanted to delete is I wish to get rid of those points once I know which cell they are in.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the vector data inside the functions and yet you have passed it as *pass by value*. Instead, you should have passed it to the function as *pass by reference*

[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373419/4588867). 
This works correctly I guess.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<float> linspace(float start, float end, int step);
vector< vector<float> > angleDisc(vector < vector<float> > &data, int theta_loc);
vector< vector<float> > ringDisc(vector < vector<float> > &data, int r_loc);

const float R_M = 18, RESO_R = 80;
const float RESO_THETA = 60;
const float PI = 3.14159;

const vector<float> DIS_R = linspace(0, R_M, RESO_R);
const vector<float> DIS_THETA = linspace(0, PI/2, RESO_THETA);

vector<float> linspace(float start, float end, int step){
    vector<float> stairs;
    float increment = (end - start) / step;
    for (int i = 0; i <= step; i++){
        stairs.push_back(i * increment);
    }
    return stairs;
}

vector< vector<float> > angleDisc(vector < vector<float> > &data, int theta_loc){
   vector< vector < vector<float> > > pieced_disc( DIS_THETA.size() );
   float angle;

   for (int i = 0; i < DIS_THETA.size(); i++){
       for (int k = 0; k < data.size(); k++){
           angle = abs(atan( data[k][1] / data[k][0]));
           cout<<"angle: "<<angle<<"\n";
           if ( (angle > DIS_THETA[i]) && (angle <= DIS_THETA[i+1]) ){
               pieced_disc[i].push_back(data[k]);
               data.erase(data.begin() + k);
           } 
       }
   }
   return pieced_disc[theta_loc];
}


vector< vector<float> > ringDisc(vector < vector<float> > &data, int r_loc){
   vector< vector < vector<float> > > ringed_disc( DIS_R.size() );
   float r;

   for (int i = 0; i < DIS_R.size(); i++){
       for (int k = 0; k < data.size(); k++){
           r = sqrt(pow(data[k][0], 2) + pow(data[k][1], 2));
           if ( (r > DIS_R[i]) && (r < DIS_R[i+1]) ){
               ringed_disc[i].push_back(data[k]);
               data.erase(data.begin() + k);
           }
       }
   }
   return ringed_disc[r_loc];
}


int main() {
    vector < vector<float> > inner = {{0.1, 0.000001},{1,-2},{-2,3},{1,3},{6,1},{4,-4},{1,3.2},{4,5.7}};
    vector< vector<float> > angled = angleDisc(inner, 0);
    vector< vector<float> > ringd = ringDisc(inner, 0);

    for(int j = 0; j < angled.size(); j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        cout << angled[j][i] << " ";
        }
        cout << "next" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < ringd.size(); j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        cout << ringd[j][i] << " ";
        }
        cout << "next" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps they wish to operate on copies of `data`.